# IF statement not working with OR

Tags: php

For some odd reason, I can NOT debug this for the life of me..
$this->input->post('post_page') = 10.... I echo the variable and it does print 10 to the screen.
This keeps returning false when it should be true..
So... can someone help me out with this? I tried putting individual parentheses around each check AND changing the || to OR.. still nothing.

Here is my code nonetheless:

```
if($this->input->post('post_page') <> 10 
                || $this->input->post('post_page') <> 25 
                || $this->input->post('post_page') <> 50 
                || $this->input->post('post_page') <> 75) {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? This if will always return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use

```
if(!($this->input->post('post_page') == 10 
                || $this->input->post('post_page') == 25 
                || $this->input->post('post_page') == 50 
                || $this->input->post('post_page') == 75)) {
            return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

<> is equivalent to NOT EQUAL.

10 is NOT EQUAL to 25 hence it will enter the if statement and return false;

In fact, it will ALWAYS enter that if statement regardless of number

You could instead do this:

```
if($this->input->post('post_page') <> 10 
                && $this->input->post('post_page') <> 25 
                && $this->input->post('post_page') <> 50 
                && $this->input->post('post_page') <> 75) {
            return false;
        }
```

In psuedo code:

```
IF 
MY NUMBER IS NOT 10 
AND IT IS NOT 25
AND IT IS NOT 50 
AND IT IS NOT 75
    RETURN FALSE
```

Or even better:

```
$allowedNumbers =  array(10,25,50,75);
if(!in_array($this->input->post('post_page'), $allowedNumbers)) {
    return false;
}
```

much easier to add new items to the list too. Any number you add to the array will not return false.

PSEUDO CODE for this one:

```
ALLOWED NUMBERS ARE 10,25,50,75
IF(MYNUMBER IS NOT IN THE LIST OF ALLOWED NUMBERS)
    RETURN FALSE
```

Comment: I'm confused... I guess I always get confused during IF statements, but IF 10 does not equal 10, then return false.. but it does... Do I have to do && instead of ||??

Comment: What I'm TRYING TO DO is say if what they type in does NOT equal any of those numbers, then return false since it has to be either of those 4 numbers..

Comment: @Peanut, thanks for clarification, ive updated the answer, actually you could have just swapped || for &&

Answer (score 0):

Translated in boolean: 
false or true or true or true.
The expression is true, therefore it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

```
(                          #
   (A is not B)            #  IS ALWAYS TRUE
   OR (A is not C)         #  --------------------------
   OR (A is not D)         #  Unless 2 conditions (AND):
   OR (A is not E)         #    . A is not B
)                          #    . B = C = D = E
```

So yes, in your case, this will always be FALSE, sorry for you.